# With Ajax and MVC 3, how can I pass values from one partial View to another partial View on the same page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a project with that has a Tasks View in it. It contains the following code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tasks";
}         

<div>
<div>@Html.Action("TaskList", "Dispatch", new { hidAccId = "3", hidUserId = "0" })</div>
<div>@Html.Action("TaskDetail", "Dispatch")</div>  
</div>
```

So, when the Task View is rendered, it actually calls up two other partial views.

The first partial view basically gives me a table of tasks.. very little information. I have it so that when I select a row of data, it highlights and gives me a row id.

My second partial view(positioned below the first on the same page) shows the detailed Task.

The idea is to take the selected row id from the first partial View and give it to the second partial view's form.  Using Ajax to submit the form and retrieve the newly selected Task detailed information.

How do I accomplish this?  I'd like to be able to do it without destroying the first partial view with a refresh of the second.

Many thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the div with the "TaskDetail"-view a unique id.

```
<div id="taskDetailsDiv">@Html.Action("TaskDetail", "Dispatch")</div>
```

In the TaskListView add code to attach javascript function to update details view:

```
<% foreach (TaskListRow row in ViewData.Model)
//make tablerows and add this for data that will trigger an update of details view
<a href="javascript:DisplayEditView(" + row.uniqueId + ")">Edit</a>
%>

//Add this at the bottom of the list view
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function DisplayEditView(uniqueRowId){
var url = '@(Url.Action("TaskDetail", "Dispatch"))';
url += "\?id" + uniqueRowId;
$.get(url, function(data){
$("taskDetailsDiv").html(data.toString);
}
}
</script>
```

This will use jquery and ajax to retrieve and display the data without a page refresh.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, tried them both and both worked nicely for me.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Say your TaskList partial view is as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            TaskCol1
        </th>
        <th>
            TaskCol2
        </th>
        <th>
            TaskCol3
        </th>
        <th>
            TaskCol4
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskCol1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskCol2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskCol3)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskCol4)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.TaskId)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

while your TaskDetail partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Task</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskCol1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskCol1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskCol1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskCol2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskCol2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskCol2)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskCol3)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskCol3)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskCol3)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskCol4)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskCol4)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskCol4)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

You can handle the click event of the table row calling your server side method via ajax:

```
$(function () {
    $("tr").click(function () {
        var itemId = $("input[type='hidden']", this).val();

        $.getJSON("/Home/GetDetails", { id: itemId }, function (data) {
            $("#TaskId").val(data.TaskId);
            $("#TaskCol1").val(data.TaskCol1);
            $("#TaskCol2").val(data.TaskCol2);
            $("#TaskCol3").val(data.TaskCol3);
            $("#TaskCol4").val(data.TaskCol4);
        });
    });
});
```

Finally, your controller must have the following method:

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int id)
{
    TaskEntities entities = new TaskEntities();

    var item =
        (from t in entities.Tasks
        where t.TaskId == id
        select t).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```